# how to insert space in Integer (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project with qr code generator, i want to make my integer "ID" insert space in 2 numbers. "ID" is auto generate number in sql database, i don't know how to add space in integer. When some ID with 4 number or above, i want to make space between every 2 numbers, how can i make it possible?

Example:

```
Dim ID As String, NewID As String
ID = 1234
NewID = ${ID} {ID}
```

Expected Answer:

ID: 1234

NewID: 12 34

I have tried to use convert integer to string, but i realise my "ID" is auto generate number

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-string-insert(system-int32-system-string) or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-8.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)

Comment: How many digits will this number be? Will it always be 4? I'm guessing not. It's rather frustrating when people provide a single example but no explanation of the general case, because it's the general case you need to code for. There are countless ways to achieve the desired result for that one example but many would not work for other cases that you need but have not described. Can this number have any number of digits? If so, what should the output look like in other cases? is it actually the case that you want a space before each second digit from the right?

Comment: Also, you need to distinguish between what's a number and what is text. In your code, you have declared `ID` as type `String`, so it's text. You assign a number but that will be converted to text. If you had `Option Strict On`, which you should, then that code would not even compile. You should start with an actual number and then format that as text in the appropriate manner. We need to know the general case to know what that manner would be.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it might keep adding new person so it won't be only 4 digits

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Please edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information. Your comment only addresses part of what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your number is an `Integer` and that you want it in two-digit groups separated by spaces, you can use `"## ## ## ## #0"` as the format specifier and then call `TrimStart` to remove the superfluous spaces, e.g.

```vb
Dim n = 1

Console.WriteLine($"{n:## ## ## ## #0}".TrimStart())

n = 123

Console.WriteLine($"{n:## ## ## ## #0}".TrimStart())

n = 12345

Console.WriteLine($"{n:## ## ## ## #0}".TrimStart())

n = 1234567

Console.WriteLine($"{n:## ## ## ## #0}".TrimStart())

n = 123456789

Console.WriteLine($"{n:## ## ## ## #0}".TrimStart())
```

The largest 32-bit integer has 10 decimal digits, so that will cover all positive values. You can encapsulate that if you like, to make using it simpler. For instance, you might create an extension method like so:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module IntegerExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function Format(source As Integer) As String
        Return source.ToString("## ## ## ## #0").TrimStart()
    End Function

End Module
```

and then do this:

```
Dim n = 1

Console.WriteLine(n.Format())

n = 123

Console.WriteLine(n.Format())

n = 12345

Console.WriteLine(n.Format())

n = 1234567

Console.WriteLine(n.Format())

n = 123456789

Console.WriteLine(n.Format())
```

If you can't use string interpolation or extension methods then you can just replace this:

```vb
$"{n:## ## ## ## #0}".TrimStart()
```

to this:

```vb
String.Format("{0:## ## ## ## #0}", n).TrimStart()
```

or this:

```vb
n.ToString("## ## ## ## #0}").TrimStart()
```

Comment: I am using .net framework 1.1, how to convert in 1.1 to use, i can use this format in other .net framework

Comment: @Reborn, see my edit, but I strongly recommend that you upgrade VS and your .NET version. You can get VS Community 2022 for free and target from the latest version back to .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: but how do i upgrade to .net framework 2.0

Comment: @Reborn, any version of VS from 2005 onwards can target .NET Framework 2.0, but be aware that 4.7.2 is that oldest version that is still supported by Microsoft. I would advise using the latest version you can and preferably 3.5 as an absolute minimum. Only use earlier if a specific client requires it. If you have anything further on this subject, you should post a dedicated question about it.

Comment: @Reborn, I forgot to mention that, assuming you're using a VS version that supports the new version you want, you can simply select a later .NET version in the project properties. In the vast majority of cases, all code you have should just work, even if some may no longer be the best way to achieve an end.

Comment: my visual studio is 2003

Comment: @Reborn, so upgrade.

Comment: @jmcihinney but i am on a old project used visual studio 2003 and .net framework 1.1 also connected to iis for write the code, how to upgrade?

Comment: I already said *"If you have anything further on this subject, you should post a dedicated question about it"*. The comments on an unrelated question is not the place for this. I will say no more on the subject.